# 'NSUnknownKeyException' when using UILabel as a function parameter

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
func textSwitch(t: UILabel) {
    if(t.hidden == true) {
        t.hidden = false
    }
    else{
        t.hidden = true
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var recordingtext: UILabel!
@IBAction func recordButton(sender: UIButton) {
    textSwitch(recordingtext)
}
```

Running it results in the NSUknownKeyException. I am very new to iOS and Swift. Can anyone help me understand not just how to fix this, but why the code will not run? From looking at other questions it looks as if this exception is normally thrown when the object being referenced doesn't exist, but I do not believe that is the case here? I really don't know enough to be certain at this point.

Comment: Insert a `print (recordingtext)` right above the call to `textswitch`  and see what it contains.

Comment: Did you correctly assign the `IBOutlet` for `recordingtext`?

Comment: The program doesn't get far enough to actually print anything. Here is the error message:

_2015-01-08 13:53:32.455 Pitch Perfect[2828:73688] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Pitch_Perfect.ViewController 0x7fabe071e960> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key recordingButton.'_

Comment: You have a discrepancy. You're specifying "recordButton" in your code, but the key you're using "recordingButton"

Comment: I fixed the discrepancy and it still throws the exception

Comment: Your xib / storyboard is broken

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination controller is probably not defined.